# How to get complete(include hour,minute and seconds) date format of datepicker value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the UI DatePicker from jQuery UI as the stand alone picker.. i have this code

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

And the follow JS

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

When i try to return the value with this code:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
```

I am returned this...

```
Sun Nov 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Which is totally the wrong format... Is there a way i can get the format like

```
Sun Nov 01 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

??

Comment: Use dateFormat of Datepicker plugin see more at http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTimePicker to specify the dateFormat and timeFormat something like this :

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    timeFormat:  "hh:mm:ss"
});
```

Or else you can try adding **get method** like :

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'D M dd yy',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes()+": "+d.getSeconds();
            $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
        },
    });
});
```

Check fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5qkt8e06/62/